# How can I Change the decimal saperator to "," (comma) without changing the culture settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller

I'm using String Format {###,###,##0.00} and Currency Format {0:N2} which gives me 9,203.25  , but I need
9.203,25 without changing the culture. Please suggest a formatting change .
Thanks..

Comment: `String.Format` is designed specifically to convert data to human-readable formats, including localization. It is not a data serialization format. If you don't want localization you shouldn't be using `String.Format`; why do you think you need to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can copy the [`NumberFormatInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo) from the current culture, and edit to your taste.

The properties [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator?view=net-5.0) and [`NumberGroupSeparator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator?view=net-5.0) control the decimal and thousands separators.

```
var info = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
info.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
info.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
        
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(info, "{0:N2}", 9203.25)); // 9.203,25
```

[See it here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gfuw2y).

Alternatively, if you don't want to inherit any formatting settings from the current culture, you can start with the invariant culture:

```
var info = new NumberFormatInfo()
{
    NumberDecimalSeparator = ",",
    NumberGroupSeparator = ".",
};

Console.WriteLine(string.Format(info, "{0:N2}", 9203.25)); // 9.203,25
```

[See it here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GZscao).